# Build numbers in PEP427 must start with digit-why?

Tags: python-wheel

According to [PEP 427](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/binary-distribution-format/#binary-distribution-format), build numbers in Python wheels must start with a digit.

Yet, it seems quite natural to use the git hash of the associated codebase to UID the wheel, so for example I could create a wheel `foo-1.2.0-ae572b-cp39-cp39-macosx_13_0_arm64.whl` when I don't want to bump the version numbers.

But since the standard explicitly prohibits this (except in the somewhat probable case that the first hex digit of the git hash is a decimal digit), I think I have misunderstood the purpose of the build number in the wheel.

What is incorrect about my mental model of how PEP 427 build numbers should be used, and what is the better way to achieve my goal?

As an aside, it appears [eggs](https://logc.github.io/blog/2014/04/01/python-egg-tagged-with-git-commit-hash/) support this.